Compute the pullback and d$(f\circ F)$ of a vector field in $\mathbb{ R}^3$

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ be the function
$$\tag1f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$$ and let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be
the following map (the inverse of the the stereographic projection):
$$\tag2F(u,v)=\bigg(\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1}, \frac{2v}{u^2+v^2+1},
 \frac{u^2+v^2-1}{u^2+v^2+1}\bigg)$$
Compute $F^*$d$f$ and d$(f\circ F)$ separately.

I try  compute $F^*$d$f$ by first finding:
$$\tag3\omega=\text{d}f=\text{d}(x^2+y^2+z^2)=2x\text{d}x+2y\text{d}y+2z\text{d}z$$
Then, to compute $F^*\text{d}f=F^*\omega$ I have the given formula by Lee's book:
$$\tag4F^*\omega=(\omega_j\circ F)\text{d}F^j$$.
So I  list up:
$$\tag5(f\circ F)= \bigg( \frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1} \bigg)^2+\bigg( \frac{2v}{u^2+v^2+1} \bigg)^2+\bigg( \frac{u^2+v^2-1}{u^2+v^2+1} \bigg)^2$$
and
$$\tag6\omega=2x\text{d}x+2y\text{d}y+2z\text{d}z$$
By the formula I have
$$\tag7F^*\omega=(\omega_j\circ F)\text{d}F^j$$
$$\tag8F^*\omega=2\bigg(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+1}\bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+1} \bigg)+2\bigg(\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+1}\bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+1} \bigg)+ 2\bigg(\frac{2z}{x^2+y^2+1}\bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\bigg(\frac{2(x^2+y^2-1)}{x^2+y^2+1} \bigg)$$.
The last term vanishes, while the first two equal to:
$$\tag9F^*\omega=\bigg(\frac{4x(2(x^2+y^2+1)-4x^2)}{(x^2+y^2+1)^3}\text{d}x\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{4y(2(x^2+y^2+1)-4y^2)}{(x^2+y^2+1)^3}\text{d}y\bigg)$$.
However,  $F:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ and the result here is in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
So I try a different approach.
Since the pullback is asked for $\omega$, without any specification, I let $\omega=v\text{d}u+u\text{d}uv$
Then, I compute the pullback:
$$F^*\omega= (\omega_j\circ F)\text{d}F^j$$
$$\tag{10}=(x\circ F)\text{d}(y\circ F)+(y\circ F)\text{d}(x\circ F)$$
which should give:
$$\tag{11}F^*\omega=\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1}\text{d}\bigg(\frac{2v}{u^2+v^2+1}\bigg)+\frac{2v}{u^2+v^2+1}\text{d}\bigg(\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1}\bigg)$$
$$\tag{12}F^*\omega=\frac{4u(u^2-v^2+1 )}{(u^2+v^2+1)^3}\text{d}v+\frac{4v(v^2-u^2+1)}{(u^2+v^2+1)^3}\text{d}u$$
But this is still in $\mathbb{R}^2$
What is the right approach here?
Thanks


You really ought to simplify $f \circ F$ algebraically; 2) $F \circ f$ makes no sense as a function; 3) are you sure you're applying the formula for $F^\ast \omega$ correctly?


The codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and the domain of $F$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$, so how are you forming $F \circ f$?

Why do you think you need to form $F \circ f$ anyway? Perhaps it would help to know that if you think of $f$ as a $0$-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $F^\ast f = f \circ F$ by definition.

Just to complete the thought: as a very basic fact, you cannot form the composition $F \circ f$ precisely because the range of $f$ is not a subset of the domain of $F$.

Perhaps I am confused... Your result should be in $\mathbb{R}^2$.$\space\space df$ is a one-form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and pulling that one-form back along the map $F$ will result in a one-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as you have calculated here. What is the issue?

I see, I was not aware of this. But which of the two cases is right? One is using the function to obtain the vector field, while the other doesn't.

The second approach is totally wrong. What makes you think pulling back $\omega=u,dv+v,du$ has anything to do with the task given? The first approach starts of in the right direction but has a number of serious mistakes. In your ponderous notation eq. (8) should be \begin{align}
F^*\omega&=2\bigg(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+1}\bigg)\left{
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+1} \bigg),\color{red}{dx}+
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+1} \bigg),\color{red}{dy}\right}
\end{align}

\begin{align}&+2\bigg(\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+1}\bigg)\left{
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+1} \bigg),\color{red}{dx}+
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigg(\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+1} \bigg),\color{red}{dy}\right}\&+2\bigg(\frac{\color{red}{2(x^2+y^2-1})}{x^2+y^2+1}\bigg)\left{
\frac{\partial}{\partial \color{red}x}\bigg(\frac{2(x^2+y^2-1)}{x^2+y^2+1} \bigg),\color{red}{dx}+
\frac{\partial}{\partial \color{red}y}\bigg(\frac{2(x^2+y^2-1)}{x^2+y^2+1} \bigg),\color{red}{dy}\right},.\end{align}

Also: I believe that switching in (8) from $(u,v)$ to $(x,y,z)$ is one of the reasons for your confusion.

By definition of the inverse stereographic projection $F$ we have
\begin{align}
x&=\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1}\,,&y&=\frac{2v}{u^2+v^2+1}\,,&z&=
 \frac{u^2+v^2-1}{u^2+v^2+1}\,.
\end{align}
It is straightforward to check that
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2+z^2&=1\,.
\end{align}
Therefore $f\circ F$ is constant on $\mathbb R^2$, and $d(f\circ F)=0\,.$
In other words: For $\omega=df=2x\,dx+2y\,dy+2z\,dz$ we have
$$
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}d(f\circ F)=F^*(df)=F^*\omega=0\,.\quad}
$$
This can be checked going the hard route: By ordinary calculus
\begin{align}
dx&=\frac{2(-u^2+v^2+1)\,du-4uv\,dv}{(u^2+v^2+1)^2}\,,\\[2mm]
dy&=\frac{2(u^2-v^2+1)\,dv-4uv\,du}{(u^2+v^2+1)^2}\,,\\[2mm]
dz&=4\frac{u\,du+v\,dv}{(u^2+v^2+1)^2}\,.
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
F^*(x\,dx)&=\frac{4u(-u^2+v^2+1)\,du-8u^2v\,dv}{(u^2+v^2+1)^3}\,,\\[2mm]
F^*(y\,dy)&=\frac{4v(u^2-v^2+1)\,dv-8uv^2\,du}{(u^2+v^2+1)^3}\,,\\[2mm]
F^*(z\,dz)&=4\frac{u^2+v^2-1}{(u^2+v^2+1)^3}(u\,du+v\,dv)\,.
\end{align}
Summing up:
\begin{align}
F^*\omega&=2\frac{4u(-u^2-v^2+1)\,du+4v(-u^2-v^2+1)\,dv+4u(u^2+v^2-1)\,du+4v(u^2+v^2-1)\,dv}{(u^2+v^2+1)^3}\\[2mm]
&=0\,.
\end{align}

That was a tricky exercise. Thanks!

@Superunknown . It was straightforward ordinary calculus at undergraduate level. The real problems I believe you are still having are highlighted in my comments to OP.

This might be easier to see by working more generally. Let $x^\mu:=\{x^1,x^2,x^3\}=\{x,y,z\}$ and let $y^{\gamma}:=\{y^1, y^2\}=\{u,v\}$. Then we may compute $F^*(df)$ as;
$$F^*(df)=F^*(2x^{\mu}dx^{\mu})=F^*(2x^{\mu}) \space F^*(dx^\mu)$$
$$=2F^*(x^{\mu})\space d(F^*(x^{\mu}))=2(x^\mu\circ F) \space \partial_{\gamma}(x^\mu\circ F)dy^{\gamma}$$
$$=2F^{\mu}\cdot \partial_{\gamma}(F^{\mu})dy^{\gamma}$$
Now computing $d(f\circ F)$ yields;
$$d(f\circ F)=\partial_{\gamma}(f \circ F)dy^{\gamma}=(\partial_{\mu}f\cdot \partial_{\gamma}F^{\mu})dy^{\gamma}$$
$$=2x^{\mu}\cdot\partial_{\gamma}(F^{\mu})dy^{\gamma}$$
So our expressions will be equal for both $F^*(df)$ and $d(f\circ F)$. Performing the specific calculations then reveals;
$$2F^{\mu}\cdot\partial_{\gamma}(F^{\mu})dy^{\gamma}$$
$$=2F^{\mu}\cdot\partial_{u}(F^{\mu})du+2F^{\mu}\cdot \partial_{v}(F^{\mu})dv$$
$$=2(x\partial_{u}(x)+y\partial_{u}(y)+z\partial_{u}(z))du+2(x\partial_{v}(x)+y\partial_{v}(y)+z\partial_{v}(z))dv$$
Which after some tedoius computation will show;
$$F^*(df)=d(f\circ F)=0$$

Thanks Volk.. !!
